# HTML in Jekyll RSS feed -- to MailChimp

Tags: html, rss, jekyll, mailchimp, cdata

I created an RSS feed with Jekyll and I want to use this to power an RSS campaign in MailChimp.

Is it possible to import or preserve the HTML tags from each blog post?

I tried generating an RSS feed without CDATA in `<description>` and the post content was dumped into a `<span>`. I lost paragraph breaks and headers.

I added CDATA and the result is all the HTML tags are parsed as if they were text, so < becomes `&lt;`. And they appear in the MailChimp email preview as if they were text.

Is there a way for MailChimp to recognise the HTML tags?

The feed url is http://www.bodhinyanagroup.org.uk/readingsfeed.xml.